# How to use variable in an sql statement when the variables have special characters

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dataset

I am attempting to select columns of data from several different tables in a for loop, and each of the table names begin with numbers, titled 0_training_market through 155_training_market.
To use a table beginning with a number in an sql statement, I have to use an extra pair of quotations around that title, which just turns my variable into a string and doesn't read the actual variable. Here is my code and error:

```
for j in list(range(156)):
    generation = str(j)+'_training_market'
    energy_source = db.query(" SELECT energy_source FROM " + generation + " WHERE id < 100 ORDER BY id ")
    quantity = db.query(" SELECT quantity FROM " + generation + " WHERE id < 100 ORDER BY id ")

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 1:  SELECT energy_source FROM 0_training_market WHERE id < 100 ...
                                   ^

[SQL:  SELECT energy_source FROM 0_training_market WHERE id < 100 ORDER BY id ]
```

I'm not sure how to work around this, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL needs to have doublequotes around badly named objects:

```
for j in list(range(156)):
    generation = str(j)+'_training_market'
    energy_source = db.query(""" SELECT energy_source FROM "{}" WHERE id < 100 ORDER BY id """.format(generation))
    quantity = db.query(""" SELECT quantity FROM "{}" WHERE id < 100 ORDER BY id """.format(generation))
```